# Change style of an object without interactions

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

I would like to make a stroke on a map when I select an object in OpenLayers3 like this site when you click on a metro station :

http://vis.oobrien.com/tube/#tongues

For that I tried that :

```
map.on('click', function(evt)
        {
            // Delete the overlay if it's not null

            if (overlay = 'undefined'){map.removeLayer(overlay)};

            // Remove popups
            $(popup).remove();
            popup = null;

            var coord = evt.coordinate;

            var feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel, 
                function(feature, layer) 
                {
                    return feature;
                },null,
                function(layer) 
                {
                    return layer == vector1;
                }
                );

            spawnPopup(coord,feature);
        }
    );

function spawnPopup(coord,feature)
{

    if (feature) {

            var props = feature.getProperties();
            console.log(props);

        }

    var test = null;

    popup = $("<div class='tad_popup'><div id='tad_close_popup' onclick='destroyPopup()'></div><div id='tad_text_popup'><p>Arr&ecirc;t "+  props.num + "</p><p>"+  props.nom + "</p></div></div>");

    var test = $(props.geometry);

    var overlay = new ol.Overlay({
        element:popup
    });

    var overlay_test = new ol.layer.Vector({source: test,
                                            style: new ol.style.Style
                                            ({
                                            image: new ol.style.Circle
                                                    ({
                                                    radius: 5,
                                                    fill: new ol.style.Fill({color: 'rgba(255,100,100,0.9)'}),
                                                    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke ({color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)',width: 2})
                                                    })})});

    overlay.setPosition(coord);
    map.addOverlay(overlay);
    map.addLayer(overlay_test);
```

But it's not the solution .

What can I do for that ?

Thank you very much.

Geo-x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use the [Select](http://openlayers.org/en/master/apidoc/ol.interaction.Select.html?unstable=true) interaction, and then set the `style` property in the constructor. Or manually add a feature (that you get with `forEachFeatureAtPixel` in a click event handler) to a [feature overlay](http://openlayers.org/en/master/apidoc/ol.FeatureOverlay.html?unstable=true) with a custom style, like in this example: http://openlayers.org/en/master/examples/vector-layer.html

Comment: It's perfect !I tried to use "new ol.Overlay" and not "new ol.FeatureOverlay" that's why it wasn't okay. Thank you for your help.